# Oracle Database Table Column Timestamp

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to create a table in my Oracle Database with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE orderlines(collectionTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);
```

An example of a timestamp that will be going in a row is:

```
20-01-2015 11:33:48-04:00
```

What would be the best datatype to use to store this timestamp?
TIMESTAMP, or DATE?

Also, what would the format be?

When I tried to import my CSV file containing all of the timestamps, SQL Developer Import Wizard didnt like the formatting. I tried

```
DD-MM-YYYY HH24:SS:MM-TZ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the best datatype to use to store this timestamp? TIMESTAMP, or DATE?

The **TIMESTAMP** datatype is an extension to the **DATE** datatype. In addition to the datetime elements, the TIMESTAMP datatype holds fractions of a second. It comes in two forms, **TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE** and **TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE**. So, if you want the precision till fraction of seconds along with the timezone elements, go for TIMESTAMP. Else, a DATE data type will give you datetime elements.

> Also, what would the format be?

Format is only for **DISPLAY**. So use the format model which you would like to display. You need to use `TO_CHAR` and a proper format model. For example,

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM
-------------------
01/21/2015 11:02:27

SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss am') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM/DD
----------------------
01/21/2015 11:03:04 am

SQL>
```

> When I tried to import my CSV file containing all of the timestamps,
>   SQL Developer Import Wizard didnt like the formatting.

That is the issue with your **locale-specific NLS_DATE_FORMAT**.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS-TZH:TZM'. This is the mask that would be recognized by `to_timestamp_tz`. Notice that MM is for months and MI is for minutes. Also, you had hours:seconds:minutes in your mask, but that would result in a wrong value not an error.